Direct volume pass as a mask instead of the volume's color
I'm using the volume direct pass for a smoke sim I have but that seems to give me the image of the smoke instead of a mask of where the smoke is and isn't so it becomes a problem when I'm trying to make a pass for purely black smoke. is there a way around this? Gray smoke and black smoke as examples
I know I could make the smoke white but that will effect the reflections on other objects in the scene



I don’t remember… does the smoke pass have an alpha channel that can be separated from it? It looks like it does from the preview.

@TheLabCat I'm not at a PC right now  to check, but as far as I know you're
right, this should be alpha transparency. It uses the max bounces for Transparent, which is for alpha channel transparency. But of course it needs to be rendered over a transparent background. desperrrr: VolumeDir only shows (like DiffDir for diffusion) the direct color, not any bounced light (that's the "...Ind" channels) or transparencies (that's the alpha channel).

I clicked the display alpha channel in the top right and the whole thing turned out white although i have figured out a makeshift solution which i will write an answer for once i have some time

@desperrrr Sure everything turned out white. The Alpha output shows the tranparent areas of the image, not just the smoke. That's why I said you have to render it over a transparent background: smoke alpha. Then you can use that alpa to put something else in the background: replace alpha
